# Evaluate F-score for individual label by cross validation in multi-label classification

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, multilabel-classification

I have a multi-label dataset and I want to determine the F-score value for each individual label with cross-validation test. Is there any example code implemented in sklearn or skmultilearn? Its documentation seems to provide only value for the entire dataset.

Answer (score 2):

You can use scikit-learn's classification report, suppose you have y and y_predict

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
y = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
y_pred = [1, 0, 2, 2, 1]
classes = {'Banana':0,'Apple':1,'Orange':2}
print(classification_report(y, y_pred,target_names=classes.keys()))
```

output

```
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

     Banana       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
      Apple       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
     Orange       1.00      0.67      0.80         3

avg / total       0.60      0.40      0.48         5
```

Alternatively you can use

```
print(f1_score(y, y_pred,average=None))
```

and you'll get the label scores in a list

```
[ 0.   0.   0.8]
```

Of course you can use a ***[KFolds iterator](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html)*** and go through all the folds and get their f1 for each label, but I dont see why you'd want to do that.

In a case where you're using cross validation, you can get, an f1 score per fold, this is because the scoring is used to evaluate the model and choose the best. see the example below

```
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
clf = svm.SVC()
cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=10, scoring='f1_weighted')
```

will output an array of 10 scores, 1 per fold

```
array([ 1.        ,  0.93265993,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,
        0.93265993,  0.93265993,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what I really asked is about the multi-label data (multiple outputs (labels) with binary-class data for each label) not the multi-class data. So, the input to determine the cross-validation score should be  X, y(set of labels output) of the multi-label dataset. Using score = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=10, scoring = 'f1_weighted') would return the score for the entire dataset. Is there any way to obtain the score for each individual label?

Comment: Only way I can see is by using cross validation on each column in y i.e. on each set of labels. somethong like `np.vstack([cross_val_score(model, X, y[:,i], cv=10, scoring='f1') for i in range(y.shape[1])])` this will generate n_label x 10 shaped array